# iOS 17 NavigationStack black screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios17

I just updated my Xcode and iPhone to the newest iOS17 and Xcode 15. Something I noticed was when I clicked my custom back button in my app I'm building, it turns it into a black screen then dismisses the screen, while swiping it away seems to still be fine. This never occurred before updating to the iOS17. Normally, once I clicked the back button, it would smoothly slide to the side and close the screen.

Here is my code that I am using:

InitView:

```
NavigationStack {
...
...
}
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { route in
                    
     switch route {
       case "LoginView":
          LoginView(path: $path)
       case "RegisterView":
          RegisterView(path: $path)
       case "ResetPasswordView":
          ResetPasswordView(path: $path)
       default:
          Text("Unknown")
     }
}
```

LoginView:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath //Navigation
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
           Button(action: {
                //back dismiss btn
                //self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() //This doesn't product the black screen.

                path.removeLast() //This causes the LoginView to turn black, and then dismisses it back to the InitView.
            }, label: {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                        .stroke(.gray.opacity(0.3), lineWidth: 3)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 8)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        
                }
            })
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
 }
```

This is irrelevant, however, this Is the code I'm using to swipe back to the InitView due to me applying the .navigationBarBackButtonHidden() modifier:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }

    // To make it works also with ScrollView
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Do you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

- Test your app on different devices running iOS 17 to see if the issue is specific to your iPhone or if it occurs on other devices as well. This can help determine if it's a device-specific problem.
- Sometimes, issues like this can be related to bugs or compatibility problems in the initial release of a new iOS version. Check for any updates or patches for iOS 17 that may have been released since your initial update.
- Use Xcode's debugging tools to step through your code and identify the point at which the black screen appears. This might provide insights into what's causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I used multiple iOS 17 simulators and all of them experience the same issue as my device. I do not understand why it clears the view, or deinits the view before it is out of view.